# Evaluate the limit behavior of the expectation expression

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

I would like to evaluate the value of the following expression:
$$M=\lim_{a \to +\infty} E_x[\frac{1}{a+x\sqrt{a}}]$$ where $x$ is subject to Gaussian distribution with zero mean and unit variance, that is $x\sim N(0,1)$.

I just want to give a strict proof that $M=0$.

It is obvious that $M$ should be **zero**, since for Gaussian distribution, $x$ concentrates most of its value to a small range and the term $a$ plays the dominant role in the denominator. But the problem is that $x$ can also approaches to infinity, even with very little probability.

Comment: Unfortunately, $$E\left[\frac{1}{a+x\sqrt{a}}\right]$$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(a)=E\left(\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{a}x}\right)\\=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{a+\sqrt{a}x}dx\\=2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{a-x^2}dx\\=2\int_{0}^c\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{c^2-x^2}dx+2\int_{c}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{c^2-x^2}dx\\=2(I_1(c)-I_2(c))$$ where $a>0, a=c^2$. Then with the transformation $x=c\sin u$$$I_1(c)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-c^2/2\sin^2u }}{c\cos u}du $$ and with the transformation $x=c\sec u$$$I_2(c)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-c^2/2\sec^2 u}}{c\sin u}du$$ Both $I_1$ and $I_2$ do not converge but I am not sure about $I_1-I_2$.

Comment: Excuse me, but could you provide more details about the answer? It is quite confusing to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, $$E\left[\frac{1}{a+x\sqrt{a}}\right]$$ is undefined.